# How to pass multiple arguments through ssh and use those arguments in the ssh script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I am trying to execute the script file **sc.sh** on remote machine **user@remote-01** using **ssh**. I also need to pass the arguments while executing this ssh command. So that i have to use those arguments in **sc.sh**.
This is my script which I am trying to execute

```
    var1=True
    var2=False
    var3=True

    sshpass -p 'pswd' ssh user@remote-01 "bash -s" < /home/user/sc.sh
```

My sc.sh looks like:

```
    if var1 -eq True; then
       echo "Todo"
    fi

    if var2 -eq True; then
       echo "Todo"
    fi

    if var3 -eq True; then
       echo "Todo"
    fi

    ..... so on
```

How can i pass var1, var2, var3 as arguments and use them in my script as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has previously been answered in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663679/execute-bash-script-stored-in-a-file-over-ssh).

however what you would want to probably do will be something like the following.

sc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3

if $var1 -eq True; then
   echo "Todo1"
fi

if $var2 -eq True; then
   echo "Todo2"
fi

if $var3 -eq True; then
   echo "Todo3"
fi
```

then run the following command

`ssh user@remote-01 'bash -s' < test.sh true true true`

arguments in BASH can be referenced by $number e.g. $1

Answer (score 1):

Finally, got the solution by trying many trial and error attempts.

```
 var1="True"
 var2="False"
 var3="True"

 sshpass -p 'pswd' ssh user@remote-01 "bash -s" < /home/user/sc.sh "$var1 $var2 $var3"
```

And should use as follows in **sc.sh**

```
if [ "$1" = "True" ]; then
   echo "Todo"
fi
if [ "$2" = "False" ]; then
   echo "Todo"
fi
if [ "$3" = "True" ]; then
   echo "Todo"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we pass the variables var1/var2/var3 as env variables on the `ssh` command line which then become available to the `bash` code on the `remote` m/c.

```
var1="$var1" var2="$var2" var3="$var3" \
   sshpass -p 'pswd' ssh user@remote-01 "bash -s" < /home/user/sc.sh
```

The contents of `sc.sh` will be:

```
if [ "$var1" = True ]; then
   echo "Todo"
fi

if [ "$var2" = True ]; then
   echo "Todo"
fi

if [ "$var3" = True ]; then
   echo "Todo"
fi

..... so on
```

Comment: This is cleaner than `export`:ing all three but not fundamentally different.

Comment: The difference lies in the fact that these are `locally global` to the `ssh` and it's children. The rest of the code don't have a clue about them and that's  the difference compared to blanket `export`-ing.

Comment: "locally global"? (-:  Yeah, just pointing out that both would work, and if the OP's script is small, it might be a simpler change to just export the variables.